# A way to find all classes with a given interface and execute asynchronously the method in each class and return the collected results?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find all classes that implement a given interface with a method of "Execute". That method would do something different for each class, but return a result of success with a message. The original class that is finding and executing those methods would then return a JSON list of those results to the front end to display.

Essentially the end product would be a user navigates to a page, clicks a button and has a progress bar run that indicates several jobs are being executed.

My understanding with C# is beginner/intermediate. I *think* I need an interface  that has a method called "Execute". And then for any job I have, I'd implement that method. My problem is now understanding how do I make it easy to get results from these jobs in a consistent format that can be parsed from the front end?

I've created a sample console app to focus on just the job portions with the following:

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using ConsoleApp1.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<Type> allTypes = GetSubtypes<IJobTask>(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            foreach (var type in allTypes)
            {
                //Just printing out the names now to see if the reflection works
                Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("----");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Type> GetSubtypes<T>(Assembly assembly)
        {
            var types = from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                select t;
            return types;
        }
    }
}
```

IJobTask.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Diagnostics
{
    public interface IJobTask
    {
        JobResponse Execute();
    }
}
```

TestJob.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApp1.Diagnostics.Jobs
{
    public class TestJob : IJobTask
    {
        public JobResponse Execute()
        {
            // Would actually call out to DB to run queries. Instead this is an example
            var jobResponse = new JobResponse {Message = "This was successful", Success = true};
            return jobResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

JobResponse.cs

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class JobResponse
    {
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can get the list of classes now, but I'm a bit lost on how to execute the method in each class. I'd like this to be an easy solution to where in the future I can just create a new class that implements this interface, and define the job execution method and it's good to go.

Comment: So far so good! You'll need to instantiate each `Type`. Look at `Activator.CreateInstance` or `Type.GetConstructor`

Comment: Each implementation has to return some JSON, according to your spec. Invoke the Execute() method (use reflection create an instance of the type and call it)

Comment: Are you using an IoC container?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, in the actual project I'm wanting to integrate this idea into I'm using Autofac. Does that change how I should approach this?

Comment: Yes it does, somewhat. Register all of the implementations with the container. Then take a dependency or `Resolve` `IEnumerable<IJobTask>` - it will give you all of the implementations.

Comment: Oh OK, interesting. I'll look into doing that (understanding of AutoFac is very minimal as well, haha). So in the future, when I want to create a new job, I'd have to update the configuration of Autofac and have a mapping for each concrete class that is implementing IJobTask?